# How do I make the ListElement not get out of the ListView in QML?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I need some help, i have the following code in QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {

    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500

    ListModel {

        id: modeloDeLista
        ListElement{
            nombre: "Articulo 1"
            precio: 5000
            descripcion: "Esto es una descripción"
        }

        ListElement{
            nombre: "Articulo 2"
            precio: 8000
            descripcion: "Esto es una descripción"
        }

        ListElement{
            nombre: "Articulo 3"
            precio: 6000
            descripcion: "Esto es una descripción"
        }
    }

    Component{

        id: vistaLista
        Rectangle{

            color: "#333"
            width: parent.parent.width
            height: 70

            RowLayout{
                Layout.fillWidth: true;
                Layout.fillHeight: true;

                Text {
                    text: qsTr("Nombre: "+nombre)
                    color: "#fff"
                    Layout.fillWidth: true;
                    Layout.fillHeight: true;
                }
                Text {
                    text: qsTr("Precio: "+precio)
                    color: "#fff"
                    Layout.fillWidth: true;
                    Layout.fillHeight: true;
                }
                Text {
                    text: qsTr("Descripcion: "+descripcion)
                    color: "#fff"
                    Layout.fillWidth: true;
                    Layout.fillHeight: true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: contenedor
        color: "#ddd"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width * 0.9
        height: parent.height * 0.9

        ListView {
            spacing: 10
            model: modeloDeLista
            delegate: vistaLista
            anchors.fill: parent
            highlightRangeMode: ItemView.NoHighlightRange
        }
    }

}
```

this looks like this:

[image]

but when you move with the mouse, you pass the gray area that is assigned to you

[image]

How do I make it so that it does not get out of there?

I had to put this to allow me to ask the question, because apparently I had little text and more code, so I can ignore this.

**Edit**

I want to keep the effect but without turning off the scroll

**Edit**

[image]

Here it leaves the container

[image]

This is what I need

[image]

How do i do it?

Comment: thank @eyllanesc but is there any way to maintain the rebound effect?

Comment: Then enable that property when you want that effect to show.

Comment: an example please

Comment: I have posted an answer, review it. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disable the overshoot effect, as indicated by the [docs](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#boundsBehavior-prop):

> **boundsBehavior : enumeration**
>
> This property holds whether the surface may be dragged beyond the
>   Flickable's boundaries, or overshoot the Flickable's boundaries when
>   flicked.
>
> This enables the feeling that the edges of the view are soft, rather
>   than a hard physical boundary.
>
> The boundsBehavior can be one of:
>
> **Flickable.StopAtBounds** - the contents can not be dragged beyond the  boundary of the flickable, and flicks will not overshoot.
>
> **Flickable.DragOverBounds** - the contents can be dragged beyond the
>    boundary of the Flickable, but flicks will not overshoot.
>
> **Flickable.OvershootBounds** - the contents can overshoot the boundary
>    when flicked, but the content cannot be dragged beyond the boundary of
>    the flickable. (since QtQuick 2.5)
>
> **Flickable.DragAndOvershootBounds** (default) - the contents can be dragged beyond the boundary of the Flickable, and can overshoot the boundary when flicked.

In your case:

```
ListView {
    [...]
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
}
```

---

**Update:**

You can set the `clip` property of the Rectangle to true, in your case:

```
Rectangle{
    id: contenedor
    color: "#ddd"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: parent.width * 0.9
    height: parent.height * 0.9
    clip:true

    ListView {
        id: list
        spacing: 10
        model: modeloDeLista
        delegate: vistaLista
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it is still coming out of the gray area

Comment: @SamirLlorente What gray area do you mean? I do not understand you, explain yourself

Comment: I've edited the code, and I put the area that I'm referring to `id: contenedor`

Comment: @SamirLlorente Do you want the rectangle to fit the size of the ListView?

Comment: @SamirLlorente What I do not understand is what you want, you could put an image of what you want to obtain, what I thought you wanted was to remove that effect of sliding the items.

Comment: it would be rather that the listview suits the rectangle

Comment: That is, you want the height of the items to change, in general it would be that the height of each item is  `container.height/number of items`. I am right?

Comment: If so, what would happen if you have say 100 items, the height of the item would be very small, how should you behave?

Comment: there are the catches, what I want is that these elements are not visible after the gray area

Comment: @SamirLlorente Try my new solution :D

Comment: In the first images you did not see that problem